# how to install kubectl autocompletion plugin for zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, kubectl, zshrc, zsh-completion

I installed ohmyz.sh , on my mac book , i want to install kubectl autocompletion plugin for zsh , but not aware of the steps to install , can any one help on this please ?

Answer (score 10):

Another option: I like having the following setup;

***~/.zshrc***: define which plugins I want to load

```
...

plugins=(
  git
  ...
  kubectl
)

...
```

***~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/****: define my custom plugins, in this case override the kubectl from OhMyZsh with the file that this command generates:

```
kubectl completion zsh > ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/kubectl.plugin.zsh
```

[image: working setup]

Answer (score 6):

According to official  [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#enabling-shell-autocompletion) documentation:

> when using Oh-My-Zsh, edit the ~/.zshrc file and update the plugins= line to include the kubectl plugin.
>
> ```
> source <(kubectl completion zsh)
> ```